# Nilpotent Elements and Units

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, nilpotence

I am trying to prove that if $r$ is a nilpotent element, then $r+1$ is a unit, but I am having trouble factoring, which is extraordinarily embarrassing. If $r$ is nilpotent, then $r^n = 0$ for some $n$ and therefore $r^n+1=1$. I want to factor $r^n+1$ into $r+1$ times something else, but I am having trouble. From what I understand, $(r+1) \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (-1)^{n-1-i} r^i$ should equal $1$, but

$$\begin{align}
(r+1) \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (-1)^{n-1-i} r^i & = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (-1)^{n-1-i} r^{i+1}  + \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (-1)^{n-1-i} r^i \\ & = \sum_{i=1}^{n} (-1)^{n-i} r^i + \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (-1)^{n-1-i} r^i \\ & = r^n + \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} (-1)^{n-i} r^i +\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} (-1)^{n-1-i} r^i + (-1)^{n-1} \\ & = r^n + (-1)^{n-1}\end{align}
$$

is clearly not $1$...What am I doing wrong!?! I realize this question has been asked before, but I am specifically concerned with the factorization part.

Comment: why do the two sums cancel in the fifth step?

Comment: Arturo's answer at the duplicate covers this already, but if it doesn't suit you, try one of the dozen duplicates linked to that post...

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with your work.. I updated my answer to let you know why that last line is "not so clearly" 1 :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer should be reminiscent of the geometric series. Let $r$ be a nilpotent element. Then $\exists n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $r^n = 0$. Then we also have that $(-r)^n = 0$, and hence,
$$\begin{eqnarray}
1 &=& 1 - 0\\
&=& 1 - (-r)^n\\
&=& (1 + r)(1 - r + r^2 - \dots + (-1)^{n - 1} r^{n - 1})
\end{eqnarray}$$
And by closure, $(1 - r + r^2 - \dots + (-1)^{n - 1} r^{n - 1})$ is in the ring too so $(1 + r)$ is a unit.

EDIT: I just realized that I didn't address your own work. Notice that in your final step, $r^n + (-1)^{n - 1} = (-1)^{n - 1}$ since $r^n = 0$. If $n$ is even, then the inverse of $r + 1$ is simply $-\sum_{i = 1}^{n - 1} (-1)^{n - 1 - i}r^i$. If $n$ is odd, then we are done since the product is equal to 1!

Comment: Where would that be if it were not in the ring?

Comment: I was just trying to take the very elementary approach mentioning every detail like "since $x \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $y \in \mathbb{Z}$, then $x + y \in \mathbb{Z}$". I guess we're all grown ups here though to that's wasn't so necessary